# Jquery prepend not working

Tags: jquery

I am practising some jquery functions and I am stuck here with prepend not working for me. Could anyone please why is it not working?

*HTML:*

```
<html>
    <head><title>BLAH</title></head>

    <body>
<div id="waterwheel-carousel-default">
    <a href="#" id="Up" class="UpLink">Up</a>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
var noofpagelinks = 2;
var count;
for (count = 0; count < noofpagelinks; count++) {
    $(".waterwheel-carousel-default").prepend("<a href=# class=PageLink id=PageLink" + count + "/>" + count + "</a>");
}​
```

*JSFiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/YGSS4/4/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using the ID selector, not class

Change `$(".waterwheel-carousel-default")` 
to `$("#waterwheel-carousel-default")`

Comment: In your own fiddle, change the framework from Mootools to jQuery and it will work

Comment: Mind if I ask on why can't we use class for prepend?

Comment: @guten_pro I think you could use a class, but in his case, it's the name of the id, so the class doesn't exist

Answer (score 5):

```
<div id="waterwheel-carousel-default">
```

Small bug in your code .

```
$(".waterwheel-carousel-default")
```

`.` is a class selector which will select the element which has the name `waterwheel-carousel-default` . But in your code your are using `id="waterwheel-carousel-default"`  . So you need to use

```
$('#waterwheel-carousel-default')
```

Answer (score 2):

`waterwheel-carousel-default` is ID, so you should use hash `#`:

```
var noofpagelinks = 2;
for (var count = 0; count < noofpagelinks; count++) {
    $("#waterwheel-carousel-default")
      .prepend("<a href='#' class='PageLink' id='PageLink"
        + count + "'>" + count + "</a> ");
}​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/YGSS4/10/

Comment: Can you tell why did you use single quotes in defining values of the atrribute?

Comment: @mabus44 It doesn't really matter what kind of quotes to use single or double.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".waterwheel-carousel-default")
   ^-----here is the problem it should be # since the "waterwheel-carousel-default"
                        is id (<div id="waterwheel-carousel-default"> )
```

also

```
prepend("<a href=#      class=PageLink    id=PageLink"

                 ^^          ^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^
 should be    href='#'   class='PageLink'  id='PageLink'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code: it works fine:

```
var noofpagelinks = 2;
var count;
for (count = 0; count < noofpagelinks; count++) {
    $("#waterwheel-carousel-default").prepend('<a href="#" class="PageLink" id="PageLink"' + count + '>' + count + '</a>');
}
```

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/fQQ68/